# How do I position arrows in the table?

Tags: pdftex

I am trying to make an impact matrix. [image] As shown in the picture, I want a red arrow from "Impacts", pointing to the right. I want a blue arrow just to the right of the rortated text "likelihood". Is this possible? So far what am getting is as shown in the picture.
Assistance will be appreciated, if possible.
My code is below

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage[svgnames,table]{xcolor} % Required to specify font color
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.5mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\usepackage{boldline, multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
%#################

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt} % for the horizontal padding
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}% for the vertical padding
\begin{tabular}[H]{p{1cm}| p{1.2cm}| p{1cm}| p{1.2cm}| p{1.2cm}| p{1.2cm}| p{2.4cm}|}
\cline{2-7}
\multirow{7}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Likelihood}} &\cellcolor{green} \scriptsize High\tikzmarknode{A} &\cellcolor{green} &\cellcolor{yellow} &\cellcolor{orange} &\cellcolor{red} & \scriptsize  Take Acition\\
\cline{2-7}
 &\cellcolor{green} \scriptsize  Medium &\cellcolor{green} &\cellcolor{yellow} &\cellcolor{orange} &\cellcolor{orange} & \scriptsize  Be Prepared\\
\cline{2-7}
 &\cellcolor{green} \scriptsize  Low &\cellcolor{green} &\cellcolor{green} &\cellcolor{yellow} &\cellcolor{orange} & \scriptsize  Be Aware\\
\cline{2-7}
 &\cellcolor{green} \scriptsize  \tikzmarknode{B}Very Low &\cellcolor{green} &\cellcolor{green} &\cellcolor{yellow} &\cellcolor{yellow} & \scriptsize  No Severe Weather\\
\cline{2-7}
 & \multicolumn{6}{l}{Impacts}\\
 & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\scriptsize Very Low/Minimal\tikzmarknode{D}} & \scriptsize  Low/Min0r & \scriptsize Moderate/Significant & \scriptsize  high/Severe\tikzmarknode{C} &\\
\end{tabular}
\tikz[remember picture,overlay]
{\draw[<-, blue, thick, >=stealth] ($(A.south)+(14pt,0pt)$) -- (B);
\draw[<-, red, thick, >=stealth] ($(C.east)+(6pt,0pt)$) -- (D);}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hm, I guessing that your intention is probably to get something like the following:

[image]

(table design is adopted to my taste )

With `tblr` table inserted into `tikz` node you can easy draw desired arrows. In MWE below are their lengths determined by trial (how width and height size of spanned columns and rows are):

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[outer sep=3pt] (m)   {
    \begin{tblr}{hline{1,Y} = {solid}, 
                 hline{2-X} = {0.1pt, fg=gray}, 
                 hline{Z} = {2-Y}{solid},  
                 vline{1,Z} = {1-Y}{solid},
                 vline{2-Y} = {0.1pt, fg=gray}, ,
                 colspec = {     Q[l]
                            *{4}{X[c]}
                                 Q[l]},
                 cell{1-Y}{1,2} = {bg=green!30},
                 cell{1,2}{3} = {bg=yellow!30},    cell{3,4}{3} = {bg=green!30},
                 cell{1,2}{4} = {bg=orange!30},    cell{3,4}{4} = {bg=yellow!30},
                 cell{1}{5} = {bg=red!30},  cell{2,3}{5} = {bg=orange!30},  cell{4}{5} = {bg=yellow!30},
                 cells = {font=\footnotesize}
                 }
High        &   &   &   &   &   Take action         \\
Medium      &   &   &   &   &   Be Prepared         \\
Low         &   &   &   &   &   Be Aware            \\
Very Low    &   &   &   &   &   No Severe Weather   \\
            &   {Very Low/\\
                 Minimal}
                            &   {Low/\\
                                 Minor}
                                &   {Moderate/\\
                                     Significant}
                                    &   {high/\\
                                         Severe}
                                        &                   \\
    \end{tblr}
        };
\draw[-Straight Barb, thick, shorten <=11mm, shorten >=3mm]
        (m.south west) -- node[above, pos=0.6, sloped] {Likelyhood}
                                      (m.north west);
\draw[-Straight Barb, thick, shorten <=19mm, shorten >=31mm]
        (m.south west) -- node[below] {Impact}
                                        (m.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello @Zarko, your design is really excellent. However on my ubuntu 22.04 it does not compile, saying "! File ended while scanning use of \environment tblr ." I suppose it's a question of linking to tabularray.sty because I installed latex-full. Thank you I can use this also.when I sort out the problem. Thank you very much. However I am very much interested in 100% tikz solution.

Comment: @ZiloreMumba, check if you have installed `tabularray` package. If not, install it! I'm sorry, but I'm not familiar with Ubuntu, so I can't help you in this.  You can test solution on Overleaf, there should work fine.  BTW, instead said "thaank <ou" you should (according to site policy) upvote answer :-)

Comment: I actually do have tabularray.sty on my installation in "/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tabularray/tabularray.sty" only I do not know how to make it usable.

Comment: Excuse my mistake, I did not copy the code up to the end. When I did, it compiles ok. Thanks.

Comment: @ZiloreMumba, ok. I'm glad that you resolve problem with compilation of my MWE. Now you only need to decide if it fulfill your expectation , how result should be, on the best way. If yes, you may consider to accept answer .

Comment: thanks once again, I think I can adopt your answer. I am sorry, that I had to switch from MS-SPO's answer, which was also very good, at least I have upvoted him to useful. Your answer responds 100% to my desire, however problem is I do not understand the code at all. E.g., if I want to increase the  row height or reduce column width, I have no idea how to go about it.

Comment: @ZiloreMumba, all this is thoroughly described in package documentation. Just some small summary: row height of particular row  change for example inserting `\SetRow{3cm,rowsep=0pt}`, where `3cm` is desired row height, before this row. Rows height can be prescribed globally, for example by  `row{2-Y} = {1cm, rowsep=0pt}` in table preamble. Columns width can be prescribed for example by `Q[c, wd=3cm]`  where 3cm is desired  column width. Also can be changed ratios between `X` columns widths, for example `X[2,c] X[c] ` etc.  where first column is twice wider from second.

Comment: Don't worry @ZiloreMumba, the better solution always beats the good one ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` (and the design suggested by Zarko).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\footnotesize
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.6}
\NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-limits=3pt}

\begin{NiceTabular}[hvlines,corners = {SW,SE}]{l*{4}{X[c]}l}
\CodeBefore
   \columncolor{green!30}{1}
   \cellcolor{green!30}{1-2,2-2,3-2,4-2,3-3,4-3}
   \cellcolor{yellow!30}{1-3,2-3,2-4,3-4}
   \cellcolor{orange!30}{1-4,2-4,2-5,3-5}
   \cellcolor{red!30}{1-5}
\Body
  High        &   &   &   &   &   Take action         \\
  Medium      &   &   &   &   &   Be Prepared         \\
  Low         &   &   &   &   &   Be Aware            \\
  Very Low    &   &   &   &   &   No Severe Weather   \\
              & \Block{}{Very Low/\\ Minimal}
                  & \Block{}{Low/\\ Minor}
                      & \Block{}{Moderate/\\ Significant}
                          & \Block{}{high/\\ Severe} \\
\CodeAfter
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [->] ([xshift=-3mm]5-|1) to node [above,sloped] {\large Likelyhood} ([xshift=-3mm]1-|1) ;  
  \draw [->] ([yshift=-3mm]6-|2) to node [below] {\large Impact} ([yshift=-3mm]6-|6) ; 
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Thank you very much @F. Pantigny. Very nice answer indeed.

Answer (score 2):

If I get you right, you probably want to have it more like this screenshot, do you?

[image: result]

A few remarks on my code below:

- I marked your tikzmarked nodes with `% <<<` to better find them; those lines may or may not contain further changes
- those tikzmarks seem to be tricky, and 2 compile runs may be necessary
- key is the last part:

```
\tikz[remember picture,overlay, >=stealth]
{
%   \draw[<-, blue, thick] ($(A.south)+(14pt,0pt)$) -- (B);
%   \draw[<-, red, thick, >=stealth] ($(C.east)+(6pt,0pt)$) -- (D);
    \draw[->,red] (E) ++(3mm, 3pt) -- +(7,0);
    \draw[->,blue] (B) ++(-6mm,-1cm) -- +(0,4);
}
```

Key steps:

- introduced an other node `E` right after "Impacts" (in table section)
- for the red line: starting at `(E)`, calculating a new position `++(3mm, 3pt)` and do a relative move to the right, say `-- +(7,0)`
- similar for the blue line, making `(A)` obsolete (please note: `A` and `B` now are before *High* and *Very*, i.e. to their left)
- moving common formatting `>=stealth` to the beginning

Finally, I wonder, if you won't do better with a 100% tikz approach, rather than intermixing tikz with a table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage[svgnames,table]{xcolor} % Required to specify font color
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.5mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\usepackage{boldline, multirow}
%\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx% not needed here
%
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
%\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}% not needed here
%#################

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt} % for the horizontal padding
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}% for the vertical padding
    \begin{tabular}[H]{p{1cm}| p{1.2cm}| p{1cm}| p{1.2cm}| p{1.2cm}| p{1.2cm}| p{2.4cm}|}
        \cline{2-7}
        \multirow{7}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Likelihood}}% <<<
        &\cellcolor{green}\scriptsize\tikzmarknode{A} High% <<<
        &\cellcolor{green} 
        &\cellcolor{yellow} 
        &\cellcolor{orange} 
        &\cellcolor{red} 
        & \scriptsize  Take Acition\\
        \cline{2-7}
        &\cellcolor{green} \scriptsize  Medium 
        &\cellcolor{green} 
        &\cellcolor{yellow} 
        &\cellcolor{orange} 
        &\cellcolor{orange}
        & \scriptsize  Be Prepared\\
        \cline{2-7}
        &\cellcolor{green} \scriptsize  Low 
        &\cellcolor{green} 
        &\cellcolor{green} 
        &\cellcolor{yellow} 
        &\cellcolor{orange} 
        & \scriptsize  Be Aware\\
        \cline{2-7}
        &\cellcolor{green}\scriptsize\tikzmarknode{B}Very Low% <<<
        &\cellcolor{green} 
        &\cellcolor{green} 
        &\cellcolor{yellow} 
        &\cellcolor{yellow} 
        & \scriptsize  No Severe Weather\\
        \cline{2-7}
        & \multicolumn{6}{l}{Impacts\tikzmarknode{E}}\\% <<<
        & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\scriptsize Very Low/Minimal\tikzmarknode{D}}% <<<
        & \scriptsize  Low/Minor 
        & \scriptsize Moderate/Significant 
        & \scriptsize  high/Severe\tikzmarknode{C} % <<<
        &\\
    \end{tabular}
\tikz[remember picture,overlay, >=stealth]
{
%   \draw[<-, blue, thick] ($(A.south)+(14pt,0pt)$) -- (B);
%   \draw[<-, red, thick, >=stealth] ($(C.east)+(6pt,0pt)$) -- (D);
    \draw[->,red] (E) ++(3mm, 3pt) -- +(7,0);
    \draw[->,blue] (B) ++(-6mm,-1cm) -- +(0,4);
}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks very much @MS-SPO, that is exactly what I wanted. You saved my day. I have upvoted your answer. However if you do not mind, just a small adjustment, I think it would look better is impacts was in the first column, just below "likelihood". So multirow{7} on column 1 becomes multirow{4}. If you have time for that adjustment I will appreciate.

Comment: Actually I would do with 100% tikz, only I did not know how to.

Comment: Fine. To adjust the blue line, just try different values for its start position `++(-6mm,-1cm)`; next adjust the relative length along the y-axis `+(0,4);`, as 4cm may be too much or not enough depending on the new start position.

Comment: Thanks for your time MS-SPO